# programming character in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, character

I have data with character time1, time2,time3 until time60. Which means each time have their own result,for example `time1=70`,`time2=56` and etc....  how to arrange this data in matrix without need to manually arrange them as:

```
time=[time1 time2 time3 time4 time5.......time60].
```

I have no idea aside from above step.  The above step is taking more time in order to type until 60 data.  Is there any easiest way to arrange these data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `eval` command inside a for-loop.

```
time = [];
for n = 1:60
    eval(['time = [time, time', num2str(n), '];']);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it straightforwardly without a loop as

```
eval(['time=[' sprintf('time%d ',1:60) '];'])
```

However, in future, try not to name your variables as `time1`, `time2`, etc. Instead, consider storing the values in a vector as `time(1)=...`, `time(2)=...`. This makes your code cleaner, fewer variables cluttering your workspace, can take advantage of vectorized operations which MATLAB is really good at (this depends on what you do with it though...) and if you need to save the values to a `MAT` file, you only need to save a single variable instead of 60.

I would also recommend against using `eval` as much as possible, and only in cases where it can't be avoided (e.g., working with someone else's code/data).

Comment: or at least put them inside a structure, which really is an associative array and allows you to lookup elements by name.  In fact, you can use `save('matfilename'); clear; S = load('matfilename');` to move variables from the workspace into a structure.

Comment: @BenVoigt That doesn't really solve the problem. First, you save _all_  variables, not just the ones you want. Secondly, you still have something like `S.time1`, `S.time2`, which is no more helpful than what the OP already has...

Comment: [Generate Field Names from Variables](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5cc-1) or [`getfield`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getfield.html)